# Override existing AS3 classes

Tags: actionscript-3

For a custom derived class "**Vector2**" from flash.geom.Point, when trying to override the **clone()** method (similar to **add()**, **subtract()** methods that will return the type itself), it will always complain about incompatible overriding 'cuz the return type has been altered from "**Point**" to "Vector2".

```
import flash.geom.Point;

public class Vector2 extends Point
{
    //Constructor is good
    public function Vector2(x:Number = 0, y:Number = 0)
    {
        super(x,y);
    }

    // Error: Incompatible overriding
    override public function clone():Vector2  //return type has to be "Point"
    {
        return new Vector2(this.x , this.y);
    }
}
```

How can we correctly **reuse/override** the methods provided by the super classes as supposed to create our own one (e.g. : a new clone1() method), or simply we just can't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't, because to override you have to keep the same function signature.
Good news is that since your 'Vector2' class is a Point, you can have a function that creates a Vector2 object and returns it as a Point. (And you can cast it back when you need it)

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are talking about is called covariant return type (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). C++ and Java, for example, have this feature, alas ActionScript does not.